# How to properly create records using :through?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a database like so:

```
class Store 
  hasMany :items

class Item
  belongsTo :store

class Order
  hasMany :items, :through => :order_items

class OrderItem
  belongsTo :order
```

First off, is this the correct way to set up this database?

And finally, how do you create records properly with multiple items?

eg.

```
o = Order.new
Order.items = [ [0,1], [3,4] ] # do you add them as an array? [order_id, item_id] ?
```

Am I on the right track for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should start here: [association basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). Rails has great documentation unlike a lot of other frameworks. It is very easy to digest and makes a great deal of sense. Also picking up a good Intro to Rails 3 book would be well advised.

To answer your question though, there are a few problems with your example above. for starters, it is `has_many` and `belongs_to` rather than `hasMany` and `belongsTo`. In terms of your modeling, you were close although I would object to your current structure.

The reason I object is because an Order should be a record that snapshots the item as it were at that given instance. Now, if you version your items, then your schema works perfectly fine. If you do not, then you need to be sure to record the relevant information about the product at the time of the order and only have the Item reference for minimal usage.

To answer the structuring question, with the way it is designed now, here is how you'd model it:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :store
  has_many :order_items
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_items
  has_many :items, :through => :order_items
end

class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :item
end
```

On to your next question:

> And finally, how do you create records properly with multiple items?

```
@order.items << item #where item is the instance of the item you want to add
```

Comment: thanks. this was spot on. i didn't know about the << method. by the way would you off chance know how to pass along a custom property? for example, I have QUANTITY in my OrderItem model, so ideally it would be like "@order.items << item, :quantity => 5" or something like that. i'm skimming the docs now but figured i would ask here as well. thanks again.

Comment: You likely wouldn't want to do it that way. Add a quantity property onto OrderItem and make it a full-fledged model rather than just a pivot to Items.